# Bluetooth LE losing connection

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy, connect

I'm developing a device that operates with Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE). It has a connection loss problem, where it connects and stays on for a while, but most of the time it connects and then disconnects. There is no time to be able to transfer anything ...
The Bluetooth chip I'm using is RN4870_71 from Microchip. I'm trying to use the Microchip app to connect via Android with the BluetoothLE chip, but I've also tried using other apps with more features.

Has anyone seen this connection drop problem occur and know how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I reset the chip, restored the factory default settings and reconfigured all parameters again. Everything works fine now.